# Can I specify which terms to show on the left side and which on the right side of an equality in output?

Tags: output-formatting, expression-manipulation

Mathematica unexpectedly moves a part of the result of the calculation to the left side where I want to display only the unknown variable.

Can I prevent this?

Comment: With version 11.3 or later, use either [`AddSides`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AddSides.html) or [`SubtractSides`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubtractSides.html). For earlier versions roll your own with [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon I just do not want the results moved to the other side. How can I prohibit it with "addsides"?

Comment: Any time you want a specific form for an expression that differs from Mathematica's default form, you will need to do some manual processing. For any other answer, you will need to provide a specific example of what you want.

Comment: @BobHanlon Here it is: ```Inactivate[
     Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]\[CenterDot]Integrate[
       g[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}], Integrate] ==
    Const + Integrate[Func, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] // FullSimplify // 
  ExpandAll // Quiet``` It moves Const or a part of it to the left

Comment: Edit your question to include your input and the desired output. It is not clear what you want. Just eliminating the `FullSimplify` will leave the `Const` on the RHS, i.e, `Inactivate[Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]\[CenterDot]Integrate[g[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}], Integrate] == Const + Integrate[Func, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] // Quiet`